# Route 53 A name record to EC2 instance not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, a-record

I have an issue with my ec2 instance hosted on AWS.

The EC2 instance has an associated Elastic ip address that I can access and confirmed is working (SSHing into the instance and changing the base index.html works fine, changes can be seen when navigating to the elastic ip).

I have a domain on Route53 and created a fresh public hosted zone. I then added an A record for my domain which routes to the elastic ip that I confirmed is successfully routing to my instance.

However, the A record `mydomain.com` just never propagates or is faulty and therefore if I type `mydomain.com` the DNS is not able to resolve it to my elastic IP. There was enough time for the records to propagate.

I would be happy to provide more information if needed.

Comment: Give us the actual domain and the IP address it *should* point to so we can take a look.

Comment: And the domain?

Comment: Your Route53 records are irrelevant - the domain isn't pointed at Route53's nameservers, so any records you have created aren't doing anything. See my answer.

Comment: I registered the domain with Route53...

Comment: I originally transfered my domains from GoDaddy to Route53

Comment: Oh got it! I found the name servers config. What do I put in there ?

Comment: the NS servers in my Route53 config ?

Comment: Yes, you need to use the new nameservers. AWS presumably copied over your GoDaddy ones when you did the transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lastlabs.com is not pointed at Route53 nameservers. Any records you set up on Route53 will currently have no effect.

```
Name Server: NS75.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
Name Server: NS76.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
```

Update the nameservers at your domain registrar to point to the four nameservers Route53 gave you.

Comment: @the_critic I see it resolving now. FYI, you'll want a second `A` record (with the same IP) for `www.lastlabs.com`.

Comment: awesome, yeah I had it all configured before. I had a CNAME for `www.lastlabs.com` pointing to `lastlabs.com`, but I recreated the hosted zone to start anew.

Comment: Note also, don't delete your hosted zone when troubleshooting -- because when you put it back, it will usually have 4 different authoritative NS records, and you'll have to go back to your registrar and update them again, which can require even more waiting.